# Pushing image directly to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ftp, db2

I am creating a web console in NODEJS where the user can manage their website information directly from a web UI, so it is easy for them to just add products and so on. My site is hosted on a paid plan with HEROKU, and basically I want to be able to select an image directly from my computer, and then when I hit submit, it sends the image to Heroku and it inserts it into the database, and uploads to the site accordingly (I have it set up with DB2). I'm not sure if this is possible, I did research a bit with FTP, but couldn't find much. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i understand it correctly but if you want to store images on your heroku instance or in database. both are not recommended.

1. Storing in database is easy to implement and use. but databases are charged per GB and storing images adds alot of size ( image size can be easily over 10MB ) so it will be very costy.
2. While storing on heroku is instance is not scalable/reliable.

Best ways to store assets is in static file storage providers like AWS S3, Digital Ocean Space, Azure Blob, etc. there are extremely cheap and provide high scabality and data reliability.

You can upload your files directly to the service provider and store the url endpoints for each resource in your database and in your web-ui just fetch images using endpoints.

Comment: yes this is answers my question. I found online AWS S3 would probably be good. I basically want to be able to just allow the user to pick an image from their computer, and then it pushes that to Heroku and updates that image for the right product on the site. I guess it would be storing it in the instance (I could be wrong)... It seems this may not be possible without using a storage provider, like you said above... thanks

Comment: it is definitely possible to store images on your heroku instance without the use of storage provider its just not recommended. There are plenty of tutorial/articles related to storing files on server which will help you better understand. And if the answer helped you in anyway please accept or upvote it 